# How do I open an EPUB from an email in iBooks on my iPad?

Tags: books, ebook, epub

I have my iPad now with iOS 5.1.  In the email I have a .epub but when iPad's email program download the file, there is no way to open it on iBooks?  Tapping or double tapping on the attachment downloaded will have no reaction.  Can this be solved if I don't have a PC to place that file into Dropbox to open in iBooks?

Comment: Might be a stupid question, but have you installed the iBooks app in your iPad? It's not installed out of the box but must be downloaded from the App Store (for free).

Comment: @動靜能量 This maybe of assistance http://www.cultofmac.com/254741/how-to-add-epub-books-to-your-ipad-without-itunes-ios-tips/

Comment: I have he same problem, but what I notice is that the email seems to recognize the epub file as a zip file rather than epub. This is why ibooks wont open it but I do not have an answer.

Comment: @ken the accepted answer to the problem is indicated below with a green check mark -- the user who asked this question has deemed this to be the answer to their problem. If that's not the solution to your specific problem you may need to ask a new, more specific to your problem, question.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In all cases I have tested, iOS recognizes epub files and will offer to send them directly to iBooks.

I have tested this from the email all, dropbox app as well as mobile safari.

Other apps like Evernote and AirSharing also are able to receive my epub files, so if you are not able to do this, perhaps it's an encoding issue or something about how the files are being attached to the emails and not necessarily a problem with iOS.

[image: epub in email]

Comment: hm... the epub i was trying to open was an epub purchased from O'Reilly, the MacRuby Definitive Guide... I wonder then if there is something wrong with it.  I later tried using Gmail in Safari on iPad, downloaded the file and was able to transfer to iBooks

Comment: There's a good chance the file didn't download correctly. I had a similar issue with a large ePub file recently inside iOS, which resolved itself when I connected to a more reliable network.

Comment: is it possible that this does not work if the mail account is not pop but imap?

Comment: Since IMAP is more tolerant to network errors and has better error recovery factors, I would say the chance that you have this error is more likely with POP email than IMAP email. All email will work once the mail and attachment download since the iOS device doesn't care at that point what protocol was used to deliver the package. (Just like when a physical package arrives - you don't care if it went by plane, boat, rail or truck as long as it arrives undamaged - all modes are capable of undamaged delivery)

Comment: Thanks @bmike when I click on the attachment it gives me a list with all available apps to open it with and when I select the iBook app. It just disappears and does nothing. No error or whatsoever

Comment: You can test whether the attachment is really downloaded by putting the device in Airplane mode, powering it down and restarting while in Airplane mode. At that point, you can try transferring it to iBooks and then reconnect to the network to take your next steps as appropriate.